# Mail like search field with tokens (Mac OS X 10.7)

Tags: cocoa, controls, osx-lion, nssearchfield

Is there a standard control for developers to get the search field behavior like in Mail (Mac OS X 10.7) to make advanced searches with tokens?

In Mail the tokens are used to visualize a search for a mail which for example was sent by a person with the name "Steve Jobs". I try to accomplish the same but in another context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is called a token field. See the [Token Field Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555). (Also [documented on the CocoaDev Wiki](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTokenField))

Comment: Then how does what you want differ from what is described in that programming guide? That might help people better answer your question...

Comment: While reading into the token field programming guide, I discovered that I can make a miked token field with tokens and plain text, that's probably the easiest way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Are there any open source projects that allow you to add advanced tokens to a search field? Like this one http://bit.ly/u5xo1X

Comment: @Tony I'm looking for the same, but couldn't find anything useful. Maybe you have to subclass NSTokenFieldCell, and implement the functionality on your own.

Comment: @brutella Did you ever find anything?